# Some issues with vue.js2 / vuetify carousel images

Tags: vuejs2, carousel

I use carousel component from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels

```
<section v-show="artistImagesList.length > 0">
    <v-carousel>
        <v-carousel-item v-for="(nextArtistImage,i) in artistImagesList" :src="nextArtistImage.image_url" :key="nextArtistImage.id" :alt="nextArtistImage.image_url">
            <div class="carousel_image_title">{{ concatStr(nextArtistImage.description, 100) }}</div>
        </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
</section>
```

Using it I need more options to control some images like

1) If images are too big in width/height I want to show images with size ratio of carousel  size. Is it possibel?

2) How set max width/height  for image area?

3) When I open page with seconds interval default I see empty carousel area and only after interval default  seconds first image is opened.
I set valid list of images, without empty elements. But looks like some empty image is opened at first.

Is it wrapper of some library? Can I get  access to its options? Please give reference to example how to make it...

**Packages used**

vue.js2.5.7

vuetify,1.0.8

Comment: Are you using axios to load your images from an api?

Comment: Try with this: [changing-the-vuetify-carousel-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067412/changing-the-vuetify-carousel-height) regards

Answer (score 2):

For number 2) to set the carousel to 400px width and height, I'm currently using the following code. But to answer 1) you can set these values to whatever you want.

```
   <v-flex xs12 style="width:100%; max-width:400px; margin: auto 0">
        <v-carousel cycle hide-delimiters style="width:100%; max-height:400px" class="white">
          <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in images" :src="baseUrl+item.url" :key="i"></v-carousel-item>
        </v-carousel>
      </v-flex>
```

And for 3, if you're getting this error because you're loading images through axios (like i was) it can be fixed with adding a v-if to the carousel. `v-if="myloadedimages.length > 0"`. This way the carousel will only be shown once the images have been loaded, and the first image will display.